# AWS custom metric for URL clicked and browser user-agent

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to create an endpoint in AWS that could collect the number of user visits (or user clicks) to different URL on a website.

My idea is to use the SDK API PutMetricData to push the values to CloudWatch. But I am unsure on how to format this "custom metric" in a way that the values can be represented correctly in a CloudWatch dashboard.

The other complication is also to determine unique user visits/clicks in the values.

The goal is to capture number of user visits per URL and per interval. If I can also capture the user-agent of the user, such as browser type, in the custom metric, that would be the ultimate goal.

I am interested to know if anyone has tried anything like this and I would appreciate any recommendation on how to achieve this.

Thanking you in advance.